# progress bar in Visual Studio 2013 in C# synchronized with a running cmd code

Tags: c#

I am making an application in which I am using the cmd to run sum command after I click on a specific button with a progress bar feedback. The problem I am facing is that the progress bar is not simultaneously working with the process, means I want the progress bar to show the progress while code is running in the cmd. What it is doing is that, when the execution of the code in the cmd finishes, the progress bar shows a 100% completion. After completion the message box is popping up. I want that it should initially show a message when the button is clicked and shows another message when the process is finished. The process finished message is working but the starting message is not working. Please help. thanks in advance.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c fastboot flash system system.img";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
    String sr = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    label7.Text = sr;
    if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Flashing System. Please Wait");
    }
    else if (progressBar1.Value == 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done System Flashing");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you are blocking the process `p.WaitForExit();`

Comment: Should I remove that line? And please suggest something about the popping up of the message box

Answer (score 0):

With the simple external command you're calling here, you can't do that. First, you're waiting synchronously for the process to exit (with p.WaitForExit()), second, you do not know how long the process will take. It may be anything from almost nothing to several hours. Of course, without parsing the output of the process, you also don't know how far it is.

The first problem can be "solved" by using a timeout with WaitForExit(int), so that you can loop until the process is done. However, that is busy-waiting, which is not so nice. Alternatively, you can move the task to a background thread, but still that won't solve the second part, which would involve parsing the output of your flash command. That, however, is a very error-prone process and tends to fail on even small changes (a new version, users having different locale settings, etc).

So, unfortunately, the only thing you can do here is show a "please wait for an undefined amount of time"-type of dialog.

Comment: I also used this code `if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Flashing System. Please Wait");
    }
    else if (progressBar1.Value == 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done System Flashing");
    }` But the 'please wait' message box is not popping up rather the 'finished' message box is working when the the process gets over.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it, as at the time you call ´progressBar1.PerformStep();´, the whole process is all done already.

Comment: So only one message box will function?

Comment: Yes, you'll always only get one MessageBox, and because you step only once, progressBar.Value will never reach 10.

Comment: Can you please rectify the code. I cant find a way out of this.

Comment: I already told you that what you want is not possible. Not unless you make risky and error-prone assumptions about the application you're calling.